# Is it okay to use a ball joint coupler to stop a hose bib leak?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I had a small leak coming from my pressure valve. I put this ball joint coupler on the end of it to stop the leak. Is this ok?

[image]

Comment: If you have winters there be sure to take it off. That doesn't appear to be a frost free valve anyway, if you drain for winter don't just open the valve take it off completely. I agree with @spicetraders answer tho, it's easy to fix.

Comment: Don't we all have winters? LOL. I think we all knew you were thinking about freezing temperatures but could not resist. + spicetraders

Comment: Freezing?  Hum it did snow for a few minutes in 1990.

Comment: I live in central New jersey, i dont think we drain for winters over here. but I do think we drain the sprinkler system. Either way thanks for the help. Ill try to get to repairing the valve over the weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Short term it is better then having a dripping valve.  In the picture the valve is a common type that is easy to repair with a new washer and packing.  [Bib washer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8j1ckzf9go)

Comment: ok thanks for the input. How hard would it be to replace the whole valve with a ball valve?  would I have to weld?

Comment: I cannot tell what type of fitting is on the back side of the bib.  It could be a threaded fitting or it could be soldered onto copper pipe.  If you can access the interior wall side of the bib then you should be able to see.  And would need that access to properly change the whole valve.

Comment: Usually it is just a rubber cone shaped seat but now it probably looks flat. With the water off it only takes a minute to pull the packing nut then open the valve until the stem comes out. The washer usually has a brass screw holding it in place.